# how to sent selected value from second class to first class indexpath.row in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
 I have two class `first` class and `second` class

I have created 3 section on `tableview` cell for display different value
If I select on section 0 and `indexpath.row` 0 then it push me on `second` class where I have all name list in `tableview` if i select any name then that name should display on first class on section 0  after it happen then i can sent this display value to server please help me on this
what i have to write on second class this method:
```

when i add this code i get this error -[airport isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e54760
2011-09-16 16:44:37.693 RegexKitLiteDemo[36975:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[airport isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e54760'

```
this is my Tfirst.m file



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"accessory selected");


    if ([indexPath section] == 0)
    {
       // load the appropriate view for the accessory selected
        if ([indexPath row] == 0)
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nameControllerDidSelect:) name:NameControllerDidSelectNotification object:viewtwo];

            viewtwo=[[Originstart alloc]initWithNibName:@"Originstart" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewtwo animated:YES];
            [viewtwo release];
}
        else{
            NSLog(@"accessory right");
            }

        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.approve animated:YES];


    }
}






my Origin.m file

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    a=(airport*)[app.lstAirports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"str:%@",a);
    cell.textLabel.text =a.Name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=a.Code;
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    a.Name = [app.lstAirports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Send notification of new selection
    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:a.Name  forKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"str:%@",userDict);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NameControllerDidSelectNotification object:self userInfo:userDict];
                 }
```

Comment: Can you write posts with some syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written you a [small example project](http://goo.gl/xyZ0A) that demonstrates how to use delegates to pass the information back from a second view controller.

It's rough - but you should get the idea.

Comment: Abizern thank for help friend but i am confuse i done with that but my data was not pass it show me NSCFStTring bec of app.lstAirports is array and i want to two value from this array name and code so takeen value like this a=(airport*)[app.lstAirports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"str:%@",a);
    cell.textLabel.text =a.Name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=a.Code; but did selected method what value to pass app.lstAirports or string a.name when i pass array which value i selected value is show on debeger but value is not passing please help me

Comment: @Rocky - I'd like to help, but I can't make sense of what you are asking. Sorry.

Comment: thank friend my problem is solve it’s my mistake i was pass string  value that why i get a error thank for ur demo application

Answer (score 1):

seems like a case of  protocols and delegate .. better read some tutorials on it.... for eg..
http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.htmlv

Comment: ya friend i know but how to use it can  u explan in step by step i read this document but not get proper

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is via a notification. Register your higher-level table view controller to receive `NameControllerDidSelectNotification` (or similar). In the second level table view controller, when `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called, add the new selection to a dictionary object and post it in a notification:

```
#define NameControllerDidSelectNotification    @"NameControllerDidSelectNotification"


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //...

    // Store the selection
    self.name = [self.namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Send notification of new selection
    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.name forKey:@"Name"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NameControllerDidSelectNotification object:self userInfo:userDict];
}
```

And back in your top-level view controller, first register as an observer of the notification (a good point to do this is when you push the second-level controller), and tell it to fire `nameControllerDidSelect:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(nameControllerDidSelect:) name:NameControllerDidSelectNotification object:nextController];

    // ...
    // [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
    // ...
}

- (void)nameControllerDidSelect:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userDict = [notification userInfo];
    self.selectedName = [userDict objectForKey:@"Name"];

    // Only do this here if your controller automatically pushes back to top-level on selecting a name, else put it in -viewWillAppear
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: self.selectedName what is this i try i get error on this line

Comment: @Rocky: I am assuming that in your controller object you create a property called `selectedName` to store the newly selected name. You can call it whatever you like, just make sure you declare it in your interface.

Comment: i don but my application is crash why

Comment: @Rocky: Apologies - there was an error in my sample code. I have corrected it now. See the first line of code under `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRoawAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Comment: please see my code what i done both class i edited now please check it

Comment: i get this error  -[airport isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e54760
2011-09-16 16:44:37.693 RegexKitLiteDemo[36975:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[airport isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e54760'

Comment: @Rocky: This is quite a descriptive error. You are calling the method `isEqualToString:` on `airport`, but it does not have a definition for this method. What type of object is `airport`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3519/discussion-between-rocky-and-studev)